# Will not the LSTM output just a single number instead of a vector of numbers

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

[image]

This is an image from an [article](https://medium.com/@aidangomez/let-s-do-this-f9b699de31d9). Here, the lstm is outputting just a single number which I think is wrong because I believe that an lstm outputs a vector of length that you decide and not just a number. So, is the article wrong or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: This is absolutely correct. Please read my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> "the lstm is outputting just *a single number* ..."

If you are referring to "[0.78572]", then the article is not wrong.

One LSTM cell only output the hidden state. And the hidden state size is determined by the `units` argument in `LSTM(units=...)`. Also, the output(i.e. the hidden state) size of a single LSTM cell is equal to the hidden state size.

Thus, from the article, the bottom "[0]" is the initial hidden state with size 1 and value 0. Since the size of this initial hidden state is here 1, the output size should also be 1, which is the vector "[0.78572]".

Another example, if that "[0]" is set to "[0,0,0,0,0]" which has size 5, then **now** the output should be a vector of 5 numbers, e.g. "[0.9827, 0.1283, 0.2845, 0.8763, 0.5344]", and the `units` argument should also be set to 5, e.g. `LSTM(units=5, ...)`.